# How to declare and use a temporary table as a cursor source in PostgreSQL?

Tags: postgresql, plpgsql

Having normalized (mostly 2NF and some 3NF tables), I now need a query like below to climb up and down my table structure to get the information I need. (PostgreSQL 9.3)

```
CREATE TEMPORARY TABLE test  AS
With charts_on_date_of_service AS ( 
    SELECT t.service_recid, t.tservice, t.chart_recid           
    FROM  ( select s.recid as service_recid, s.tservice, p.chart_recid
        from doctorservices d                   
        join services s on (s.recid = d.service_recid)      
        join patients p on (p.recid = s.patient_recid)      
        where s.tservice::date = _tservice::date        
        ) as t 
)
select s.recid as service_recid, s.tservice, c.chart_recid, c.tservice as time_of_service
from charts_on_date_of_service  c                   
join patients p on (p.chart_recid = c.chart_recid)          
join services s on (s.patient_recid = p.recid)              
join doctorservices d  on ( d.service_recid = s.recid)          
where s.tservice::date <= _tservice::date               
order by c.chart_recid, s.tservice;
```

As involved as this query is, I would like not to have to duplicate it within a plpgsql function. That is, I would like to do something like:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION test(_tservice timestamp)            
  RETURNS TABLE (service_recid bigint, chart_recid int, tservice timestamp, ct int) AS
$func$ 

DECLARE 

CREATE TEMPORARY TABLE test AS ....   <--THIS FAILS

cur CURSOR FOR
    SELECT t.service_recid, t.tservice, t.chart_recid   
    FROM   test t

BEGIN
      ... some processing commands on the temp table test and cursor cur....
END
```

I have several related questions:

- How is a temporary table "Declared" in plpgsql?
- Can a temporary table be used as a source for a cursor?
- Would performance be better creating a single temporary table and using it in multiple places, or better to recreate the identical query in multiple places?

I can't seem to find the answers with Google. 
Any help or ideas is most appreciated.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You have to use different approach. Inside PL/pgSQL any `CREATE` statement cannot be in `DECLARE` part. It is statement as any other and should be in function body part. If you can iterate on dynamically created table, you have to use [unbound](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.1/static/plpgsql-cursors.html#PLPGSQL-CURSOR-DECLARATIONS) cursor, and you have to specify query in `OPEN` statement (or better - use `FOR` cycle):

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION test(a int)
RETURNS TABLE (b int, c int, d int) AS $$
BEGIN
  DROP TABLE IF EXISTS foo; 
  CREATE TEMP TABLE foo(col int);
  INSERT INTO foo SELECT generate_series(1,a);
  FOR b, c, d IN SELECT col, col + 1, col + 2 FROM foo
  LOOP
    RETURN NEXT;
  END LOOP;
END; $$ LANGUAGE plpgsql;
```

This example works, but it is **significantly expensive** and this pattern should be used **only when it is necessary**. Temp tables are expensive, and if you don't need it, don't use it (there are good reasons: performance, complexity, but usually it isn't necessary). Some patterns from `T-SQL` are not be used in Postgres, and some work needs different thinking. You can use a arrays, `RETURN NEXT`, `RETURN QUERY` statements:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION test(a int)
RETURNS table (b int, c int, d int) AS $$
BEGIN
  RETURN QUERY SELECT col, col+1, col+2
                  FROM generate_series(1,a)
  RETURN;
END; $$ LANGUAGE plpgsql;
```

For similar trivial functions is better to use SQL language:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION test(a int)
RETURNS table (b int, c int, d int) AS $$
  SELECT col, col+1, col+2
     FROM generate_series(1,a)
$$ LANGUAGE sql;
```

You can use arrays in Postgres:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION test(a int)
RETURNS TABLE (b int, c int, d int) AS $$
DECLARE cols int[];
BEGIN
  cols := ARRAY(SELECT generate_series(1,a));
  RETURN QUERY 
    SELECT col, col + 1, col + 2 
       FROM unnest(cols) g(col);
  RETURN;
END; $$ LANGUAGE plpgsql;
```

Comment: Excellent answer. So if the temp table is very expensive, in my case, is it better to repeat the query; once for each of the two cursors I will need? Thanks.

Comment: @AlanWayne it depends how expensive is your query. The cost of temporary tables increases with frequency - 1/s in db (+/- zero), 100/s in db (pretty expensive). Always depends on context, but the behave is strongly different (and internal implementation is different too) than T-SQL. If it is necessary, use temp tables, but prefer a arrays (variables).